# Xamarin iOS Error CS7027 Error signing output with public key from file

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store

friends please help me when I publish my iOS app return below error in xamarin.

https://prnt.sc/s4fys4

Comment: "file not found" seems like a pretty obvious error message to resolve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing your certificate. Re-download and put it in that same directory then you should be fine.